# Adding background image in CSS

Tags: html, css, image, background

I'm trying to add a background image to my first panel on my one page product website. For some reason (which I can't figure out) my background image won't load. Please help!

HTML:

```
<!-- panel 1 -->
<div class="header">
<h3> Introducing the </h3>
<h1> Vespa Tribute </h1>
<p> Scheduled for release in June 2016, this limited edition scooter will only      be produced 250 times. Enter your email below to be partnered with a Vespa representative who will ensure that you stay updated and informed about how be part of this exclusive venture. </p>
<input type="text" name="emailaddress" placeholder="Email address">
<button type="button">Get exclusive Info</button>
<img src="images/vespa1.png" alt="vespa" />
```

CSS:

/* HEADER PANEL */

```
.header {
background-image: url('images/image1.png');
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Does the image load if you open it in a new tab? Does the server access log show anything useful?

Comment: Your code looks fine, it's most likely just unable to find the image. Make sure the image exists and image/image1.png is the correct path in relation to your CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

Your div isn't closed, but I'm assuming you've just not pasted the whole code.

Your CSS code says HEADER PANEL - does that mean you're not using this as a separate stylesheet? If it is in a separate sheet, you have to specify the path in relation to the stylesheet's location rather than the HTML's.

Are you working from your own machine or testing this code on a live server? Are you working in a CMS or some other such add-on with its own CSS library?

I'd recommend doing what Nathan suggested by making sure that it's the correct filepath by loading it from the address bar.

Next I'd try specifying the exact filepath if you're testing this code live - "http://server.com/images/image1.png"

After that, if it's still not functioning and the filepath is correct, try opening all of the linked stylesheets and finding any values associated with the 'img' element - remove them one by one while refreshing your page in between to locate the conflicting code.

It looks fine to me otherwise, so I'd be surprised if it's not fixed by any of these suggestions.